# Magento 2 forwarding noroute give error

Tags: magento2, controllers

I am trying to forward controller to noroute page with below code but got error.

> Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

```
protected $resultForwardFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
    \Test\Test\Helper\Data $test
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
    $this->test = $test;        
}
public function execute()
{
    if (!$this->test->isModuleEnabled()) {
        return $this->resultForwardFactory->create()->forward('noroute'); 
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Debug the dispatch function in class Magento\Framework\App\FrontController and log the error which may gives way to find exact error.
```